# Printing a string as a variable in Pascal

Tags: string, variables, printing, pascal

This is the string variable that I have:

```
question1 := 'Please enter 1, 2 or 3.';
```

I also have a function which is supposed to print out the question1 variable, but it generates the question number before printing. Here's a fragment of the function, which turns the question number (`question : integer`) into a string variable (`test : string`) and then concatenates the string 'question' with this string variable (`test : string`).

```
str(question,test);
test := concat('question',test);
writeln(test);
```

The result of this writeln is 'question1' (without the quotes). I want it to output the question1 variable as a text string, not just this variable's name, so that the writeln prints `Please enter 1, 2 or 3.` I've tried `writeln(question1)` and it works, however, it appears that my function above (or the fragment of it) does this: `writeln('question1')`. How do I solve this?

Comment: Not very clear, sorry. Could you perhaps show a wider context of what you are doing/trying to do? If you do `writeln(q1);` and it works as if it were `writeln('q1');`, then `q1` must be a string variable or function that is accessible at that level of scope and is holding `'q1'` at the time of execution of that statement. And if it is not so but `writeln(q1)` still works that way, then it must be something specific to the particular flavour of Pascal you are using. Or what am I missing?

Comment: I've updated the question.
I do not really know how to explain it better. Basically, I have a function which generates the name of a random variable (which is already defined as a particular text string) and puts that name in the writeln(). The problem is that it puts the variable name as a string value (=as text) in the writeln, which prints only the text 'question1'. What I want is for it to print the string variable question1, not it's name. This variable contains the following string and I want to print it (question1): 'Please enter 1, 2 or 3.'

Comment: Yup, that's clearer now, thanks. You want the name stored in the `test` variable to be resolved and evaluated. Hardly possible (not in standard Pascal for sure). But there might be alternative approaches to what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pascal doesn't support dynamic name resolution, like you want. You might consider using [arrays](http://pascal-programming.info/lesson10.php) instead:

```
…
var
  Questions: array[1..3] of string;

…

procedure InitQuestions;
begin
  Questions[1] := 'Please enter 1, 2 or 3.';
  Questions[2] := '…';
  Questions[3] := '…';
end;

procedure YourFunction(question: Integer);
begin
  …
  WriteLn(Questions[question]);
  …
end;

…

begin
  …
  InitQuestions;
  …
  YourFunction(1);
  …
end.
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. I can't imagine why didn't I think about arrays myself - this is such an easy solution! Perhaps I thought that there was an even easier way of doing this... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can figure out from your question, you need the following

```
writeln (question1, 'question ', question);
```

You don't need to concatenate string values, nor do you need to convert the question number to a string - writeln has the magical ability to accept any number of variables and print them according to their default format (strings, integers, reals and booleans).

In fact, you don't really need to create the 'question1' variable - you could simply write

```
writeln ('Please enter 1, 2 or 3. Question', question);
```

Comment: The problem with this is that I need to write each writeln individually, the answer above (using arrays) helped me to do it automatically, using a function and different questions each time. The point of that function is to determine a new question depending on the previous answer and put question1, question2, question3 etc in the writeln().